# How is username used in Evernote?

Tags: evernote, username

I'm trying to decide what kind of username to create in Evernote.  How is the username actually used throughout the application?  Is it ever shown publicly?  If so, in what contexts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used as part of your email address (for emailing in notes) and when you share notes or notebooks with others.

Comment: Also I would add that, AFAIK, when you share a note via a link (i.e. url) your username is neither published nor publicly visible. Would appreciate any info to the contrary (or confirmation)